# How to load an arcgis map in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I load and work on a map produced in ArcGis into a webpage that I'm building.. Please I need help, no code yet because I'm still starting the coding.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple html page, that displays a Tiled map service :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #mapDiv {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad:true };</script>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19compact/"></script>
<script>
  require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer) {
    var map = new Map('mapDiv');
    var layer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer('http://your_domain/path/to/layer/MapServer');
    map.addLayer(layer);
  });
</script>
<div id="mapDiv"></div>
```

check the API https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html, under esri/layers (menu on the left) to load the correct type of layer of your mapservice